# product and price book entry

Tags: configuration

I need some configuration where users prevent duplicate price book entry in peice book entry object.I though to write trigger but on this object we are not able to write any trigger, workflow and process builder then how to achich this?

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to write code for this. The system automatically restricts price book entries that have the same Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, and CurrencyIsoCode (if multi-currency is enabled). The error produced will look like the following:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, This price definition already exists in this price book: []